# how to changeCheckBox ControlTemplate to another shape while keeping the behaviour of "Checked" and "Unchecked" Visible?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, controltemplate

I need to make a `CheckBox` to look like a "(" shape instead of it's nomal square shape , the "(" shape should have some space inside it so that the user would observe the difference when checking and unchecking.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to change the Template in the comboBox style. This is an example of a circular checkbox:

```
   <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="CheckBox">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition />
                        <ColumnDefinition />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CheckStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Unchecked"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Checked">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="tick" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Indeterminate"/>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <Ellipse x:Name="blackframe" Stroke="Black" Fill="Blue" Width="16" Height="16"/>
                    <Ellipse x:Name="background" Margin="2" Fill="AliceBlue" Width="12" Height="12"/>
                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="1" Margin="5,0,0,0"/>
                    <Path x:Name="tick" Fill="Black" Data="F1 M 4.325,7.852 C 4.175,7.852 4.026,7.807 3.900,7.720 L 0.325,5.262 C -0.016,5.027 -0.103,4.560 0.132,4.219 C 0.367,3.877 0.833,3.792 1.175,4.025 L 4.091,6.030 L 7.478,0.365 C 7.690,0.010 8.151,-0.107 8.506,0.106 C 8.861,0.319 8.978,0.779 8.765,1.135 L 4.969,7.486 C 4.863,7.664 4.688,7.790 4.485,7.834 C 4.432,7.846 4.378,7.852 4.325,7.852 L 4.325,7.852 Z" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Opacity="0"/>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
```

If you want to change the shape, then you'll need to make a path rather than an ellipse. Blend would probably be the best place to do that.

Answer (score 1):

When you change the template of a control you basically change its visual tree.
In such case you lose the visualization of the states provided in native windows controls. 
For example if you change the template of a button, at first you don't see anything happening when you click on it.

If you work with Dot.Net 4 you can use VisualState (recommended approach) such as in the code of emybob

In case you work Dot.Net 3.5 you cannot use VisualState but you can use ControTemplate.Triggers
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.controltemplate.triggers.aspx